# A triangle inside a circle

Tags: geometry, vectors

[image]

> Find $k$ in $BC : CD = 2 : k$
>
> $AB:AC=3:2$
>
> $\vec a = OA, \vec b = OB, \vec c = OC$

What i know
$OA$ perpendicular to $AD; BD = (2+k)/2 BC; OA=OB=OC$. But geometry is just my weak point, how to find $k$?

Edit :
Radii = 1
As shown in the figure, let $D$ be a point on the extension of side $BC$ and $k$ be the number where

> $BC:CD=2:k$.
>
> Moreover, set
>
> $\vec{OA}=\vec{a},$ $\vec{OB}=\vec{b},$ $\vec{OC}=\vec{c},$
>
> Since the equality
>
> $|\vec{b}-\vec{a}|=\frac{3}{2}|\vec{c}-\vec{a}|$

Comment: If OA=OB=OC as you say, it should be an equilateral triangle. This is in contradiction with the figure.

Comment: Please clarify: are you told that AB is perpendicular to AD? That's an important piece of information and perhaps should be in the quoted section.

Comment: @Perspectiva8 $OA$, $OB$, and $OC$ are not the sides of a triangle. They are three different radii of the given circle.

Comment: Even if AB is perpendicular to AD, there is still something missing in the formulation of the problem. For example, is AB=AC? That would make a difference... Can you please tell us the source of the question?

Comment: Please check the edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Let $|AB|=c=3y$, $|AC|=b=2y$, 
$|BC|=a=2x$, $|CD|=d=kx$, $|AD|=e$.

By the power of the point $D$,
\begin{align}
|AD|^2=e^2&=|CD|\cdot|BD|
,\\
e^2&=k\,(k+2)\,x^2
.
\end{align}

By the cosine rule

\begin{align} 
\triangle ABC:\quad
\phantom{-}\cos\gamma&=\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab}
=\frac{4x^2-5y^2}{8xy}
,\\
\triangle ACD:\quad
-\cos\gamma&=\frac{d^2+b^2-e^2}{2db}
=\frac{2\,y^2-k\,x^2}{2kxy}
,\\
-\frac{y(5k-8)}{8kx}&=0
,\\
k&=\frac85
.
\end{align}

And in general case,

\begin{align}
\frac da&=\frac{b^2}{c^2-b^2}
.
\end{align}